# What is the domain jenkins.domain.tld?

Tags: jenkins, dns, continuous-integration, subdomain

This `jenkins.domain.tld` appears in the answer to a [bitbucket pull request builder question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41112705/362754).

A search turned up pages mentioning it as a `subdomain`. What is it exactly? Is that `tld` something new like the `local` special domain, or like `example.com`? If you browse to that `domain.tld`, nothing is returned.

The referenced SO answer also mentions using `http:///`. How would that be resolved by DNS or other domain resolution mechanisms to the jenkins server? If putting that into a browser, it redirects to `jenkins.com`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

tld stands for top level domain : .com, .net, .org, ...

If you want to host your own domain, you'll need to declare your domain.tld (example : jenkins.mydomain.com) in a public or private DNS.

Comment: Awesome. Thanks for clear answers to all my questions!

Comment: if you're dealing with local dev only you can also set your jenkins.mydomain.com in `/etc/hosts` (Linux) or in your `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts` (Windows). Example if 192.168.1.2 is your Jenkins IP  :

`192.168.1.2 jenkins.mydomain.com `

Comment: Great! Thanks a lot!